# same comment shows on multiple php webpages

Tags: javascript, php

i have a multiple article webpages and on that every single article i had placed a comment system below the article so people can comments anything about the article.

The problem is that whenever i do comment on any article its shows me the same comment on others article.

so people please help me out.and thanks in advance.

```js
 
      <!--Javascript of Comment System -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#comment_form').on('submit', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
   url:"add_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:form_data,
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    if(data.error != '')
    {
     $('#comment_form')[0].reset();
     $('#comment_message').html(data.error);
     $('#comment_id').val('0');
     load_comment();
    }
   }
  })
 });

 load_comment();

 function load_comment()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
  
 $(document).on('click', '.reply', function(){
  var comment_id = $(this).attr("id");
  $('#comment_id').val(comment_id);
  $('#comment_name').focus();
 });
 
});
</script>
```

```css
 <!--comment system script and css stylesheet-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

```html
    <!--This is the comment container-->
<p class="container"><h3>Ask A Question</h3></p>
<br>

    <!--This is the comment system-->
  <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <textarea name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment" rows="5" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
     <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
    </div>
   </form>
   <span id="comment_message"></span>
   <br />
   <div id="display_comment"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[fetch_comment.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xx7O7-zl0VfAz5GUVZ7ooyUO4EOUeQYQ)

[add_comment.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FnQCgIkAcOrS3lvJTpKvUg6NpGjQlrzM)

Comment: whats the code in fetch_comment.php ?. You need to fetch the comments based on article ID or something then only it will fetch comments for that article otherwise it will fetch all the comments and show

Comment: You don't show us any of either `add_comment.php` or `fetch_comment.php`, so I'm not sure how we are supposed to diagnose the problem. But having said that, the call to `fetch_comment` doesn't appear to pass any data which could allow the PHP script to know which article to fetch the comments for. I presume you are saving the comments in a database, and retrieving them from that, and that your database has some way to associate each comment with a single article?

Comment: since you didn't passed any data to the fetch_comment.php like id of the article or something. so i think its fetching all the comments from your comment table and showing it to all the articles

Comment: wait i will update this post and try to put fetch_comment.php and add_comment.php files.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're storing the article id/reference the comment was written for either. You seem to simply have a table you fill with comments, without any reference to the articles what so ever?

Comment: Your form has no articleId, so looks like you don't store the connection between comment and article. Add a hidden input with the article id to the comment form then save it on backend side. While loading comments supply your request with article id and fetch only those comments which have the articleId

Comment: I've just looked at your linked PHP scripts, and they confirm what I and various other commenters suspected - you have a single table for comments, and aren't saving anything to link comments to articles, THAT is the problem, you need to have a column in your comment table that references the article ID. Also, please post code as code, not in links, and if that's your actual database name and password showing in the code you linked to then I really hope you change the password before deploying this to production anywhere.

Comment: @Robin Zigmond comments is store in the database and it display as well the only problem i am facing its shows me a same on every single article.

Comment: We understand your problem and that is what we are saying. You need to store the article id with the comment (add a column called `article_id` in your `tbl_comments`-table) so you know what article a specific comment belongs to. Currently, you have no way of knowing what article a comment belongs to, which means that it's literally _impossible_ to get comments that was made for a specific article.

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson i have tried your solution but its not working comment is not displaying in the file.

Comment: Then you've implemented it wrong because that's the way you _have to_ do it. Each comment should have an article id. Then you should fetch the comments that have that specific article id.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your `load_comment` function:

```
 function load_comment()
 {
     $.ajax({
         url:"fetch_comment.php",
         method:"POST",
         success:function(data)
         {
             $('#display_comment').html(data);
         }
     })
 }
```

There is no reference to an article id. Essentially, you are sending a request for comments without specifying from which article the comments should be coming from. Now, let's say you do fix that by adding a request for an article_id:

```
 function load_comment()
 {
     $.ajax({
         url:"fetch_comment.php",
         data: {article_id: 0},
         method:"POST",
         success:function(data)
         {
             $('#display_comment').html(data);
         }
     })
 }
```

You still will get the same comments as a result. This is because your `fetch_comment.php` script doesn't have the functionality to be able to specify comments by `article_id`. Look at the first few lines of `fetch_comment.php`:

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=techotub_testing', 'techotub_testing', 'password');

$query = "
    SELECT * FROM tbl_comment 
    WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' 
    ORDER BY comment_id DESC
";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();
```

Here we can see that you are requesting all comments from tbl_comment, without specifying the article. What you want to do, to get all comments from a specific article, is to add a line to the `where` clause that specifies the article that you are requesting. If you are passing the article_id through a post call with ajax, you could accomplish this by using `$_POST['article_id']`

Unfortunately, you wont be able to use any kind of article filtering yet, because of your insert SQL statement:

```
$query = "
 INSERT INTO tbl_comment 
 (parent_comment_id, comment, comment_sender_name) 
 VALUES (:parent_comment_id, :comment, :comment_sender_name)
 ";
```

This tells us that you are not saving the article id on the table when you add a new comment. If you want to filter by article, you need to have an article column and specify the id on each insert. Once you do, you should be able to start editing the rest of your code to filter by article.

**tldr**

1. add an article id column to your table
2. start inserting the article id value to the table when adding a new comment
3. add a new line into the select clause to display by article id
4. pass the article id from your ajax function to your php script

Comment: thank you so much for the explanation in details. i will try to implement your procedure in my database.

Comment: @TECHHOME glad to hear. dont forget to select this answer as the correct one if it is acceptable to you.

Comment: @rtrigso i have try this procedure but comment is not displaying. but it is displaying in my database not on my .php article file

Comment: @TECHHOME once you have requested the comments by passing the article_id requested, the comments returned should be the ones belonging to that article. It is up to you to display the returned information properly. You might want to update your question with your updated files.